# Clear textarea input after enter key press

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, keycode

I was creating some chat application using JavaScript that allows one to send a message after the enter key is pressed

```
window.onkeydown=function(event){
    if(event.keyCode==13){
        sendNew();
    }
}
```

and in the **sendNew()** function;

```
var msg=document.getElementById('txt').value.toString().trim();
    if(msg!=="") {
    //send message        
    document.getElementById('txt').value = "";
    }
```

When you press the enter key when the textarea is **onfocus** the text is cleared but it seems to insert a new line character and the cursor goes to the next line in the textarea.

How can I get rid of this and have a completely empty textarea?

Answer (score 16):

> What you have to do is to cancel the default behaviour of the browser when pressing enter key (you have to prevent the browser from adding a new line).

Solution: use `event.preventDefault()`. Documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Try out this code:

```
window.onkeydown=function(event){
    if(event.keyCode==13){
        sendNew();
        if(event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault(); // This should fix it
        return false; // Just a workaround for old browsers
    }
}
```

> Some developers forget about `event.preventDefault` and write `return
>   false` instead. This is a bad practice, and I would suggest you the
>   new method.

Comment: In Chrome 53, `return false` actually didn't fix it for me, but `event.preventDefault()` did.

Answer (score 4):

Thats because the default behavior of the enter key is to insert a new line. To prevent this from happening, `return false` from the keydown event handler.

```
window.onkeydown=function(event){
    if(event.keyCode==13){
        sendNew();
        return false; // prevent default behavior if ENTER key
    }
}
```